# jQuery activator not working on multiple DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I'm making a setup where when I click one of the divs with a id of "sbox" it will make the div with a id of "box" expand and opacity change this is the jQuery I have,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  TriggerClick = 0;

  $("#sbox").click(function(){
    if(TriggerClick==0){
         TriggerClick=1;
         $("#box").animate({width:'100px', height:'100px', opacity: '0'}, 500);
    }else{
         TriggerClick=0;
         $("#box").animate({width:'500px', height: '500px', opacity: '1'}, 500);
    };
  });
});
```

Now when I have multiple divs with the id of "sbox" only the first box will do the animation:

```
<div id="sbox">WORKS</div>
<div id="sbox">This one doesn't</div>
<div id="sbox">This one doesn't</div>
<div id="sbox">This one doesn't</div>
<div id="sbox">This one doesn't</div>

<div id="box">This is the box that expands</div>
```

And lastyl, I'm not sure if this would help, but here is my stylesheet:

```
#box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
}

#sbox {
    background: blue;
    margin: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

If you have any ideas, or suggestions for my code, please please PLEASE try to help. Thank you.

-EDIT-

My goal here is to get have an array of boxes and one bigger box that is invisible, when you click one of the boxes in the array the big box expands and turns visible, when you click the same box it shrinks and turn invisible.

Comment: Id must be an unical on the page, you must use class for multiple elements with same name.

Comment: From reading your goal, it seems like you're going for something like this: http://www.red-team-design.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/interactive-menu-css3-jquery-demo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't assign same ID for different elements , use class instead .

css:

```
.sbox {
    background: blue;
    margin: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

<---end of css--->

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  TriggerClick = 0;

  $(".sbox").click(function(){
    if(TriggerClick==0){
         TriggerClick=1;
         $("#box").animate({width:'100px', height:'100px', opacity: '0'}, 500);
    }else{
         TriggerClick=0;
         $("#box").animate({width:'500px', height: '500px', opacity: '1'}, 500);
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks, forgot my basic HTML for a second. Voted best answer for and example as well.

Comment: no problem glad i have helped you , but if you care about your reputation you better remove the question , cause it will get many negative votes.